# Best place to store Datebase and Local Config setting

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and trying to start a PHP Project with sound grounds.
I have seen many website sourcecode and realized that every one make it differently.

Initially I want to Save my Database setting and Local setting like Dataformate, Currency formate etc in a config class
which is accessiable every where application without using an include.

And the I will need a good controller class i don't want to use any Framework!

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe you can set PHP variables without using include, and even if you could, it would be a poor idea. Anyone maintaining your code later will be very confused if this were possible.

What you **can** do, its create an `__autoload` function (see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) that loads a class with your variables when you need it. However this is more costly than just hard including the file.

How you might create an autoloader

index.php:

```
<?php

include("autoloader.inc.php");

$vars = new settings(); //this procs the __audoload() function
```

autoloader.inc.php:

```
<?php

function __autoload($class) {
    include $class . '.php';
}
```

settings.php:

```
<?php

//settings functions
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
//... more stuff


//variable container class
class settings {
    public static $dbuser = "billybob";
    //... more stuff
}
```

The advantage of the autoloader is that were you to not always need the information, you could avoid loading the settings file when not needed. Or load other classes as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to include a file every time in your application & assuming every request is handled by index.php you can do like,

```
$lib_paths = array();
$lib_paths[] = "c:/web/htdocs/appname/lib";  // you can more paths in this array
$inc_path = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $lib_paths);
set_include_path($inc_path);
```

assuming lib has your config class/file.

If you are looking for a controller class & as you said you are new I'd recommend reading

**Pro PHP: Patterns, Frameworks, Testing and More** by **Kevin McArthur**

It'll give you an idea about creating your controllers & other components of MVC

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Store all configuration variables to ini or yaml files (non-accessible path of webserver). I prefer Yaml files. Cause its more comfortable than ini.

For reading ini files, you can use parse_ini_file() function in php. For yaml use symfony YAML components.

Create a basic config class for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

If running apache you can use SetEnv to set up a variable that will be available in any php script by using getenv() to access it.

so in httpd.conf you might have

```
SetEnv CurrencyFormat SomeFormat
```

and you would access in your code like this:

```
$currencyFormat = getenv('CurrencyFormat');
```

However, I'm not sure why you want to avoid an include? It's certainly more standard to localize your settings to your app, and that means including something , whether or not you do a real include, or read a config.ini of some sort.